# Ссылка на комментарий игнорируя постраничную навигацию

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Появилась идея по улучшению форума, но ни как не могу понять как её реализовать. Сразу к сути: имеется форум, в каждой теме есть комментарии, также имеется постраничная навигн. При ответе пользователю другим пользователем, ему приходит уведомление в журнал. После перехода по ссылке, пользователя перебрасывает на первую страницу с комментариями. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы пользователя перебрасывали именно на ту страницу на которой комментарий? Хотел сделать так: при ответе записывается в БД страница на которой комментарий. Но проблема в том, что у пользователей разное количество комментариев на странице. Возможно уже есть готовое решение, а если нету, то подскажите, пожалуйста, в каком направлении двигаться. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так как вы знаете кому слать уведомление - то перед отправкой получите его настройку с числом элементов на странице и сгенерируйте ссылку.

Comment: Проще всего просто отдельно закрепить комментарий, открытый по ссылке. Искать корректную позицию конкретного комментария - сложно и не факт, что удобнее.

Comment: @u_mulder, Да, об этом также думал. Но проблема в том, что пользователь может сначала зайти в настройки и сменить их, а после этого зайти в журнал и в следствии этого ссылка уже будет неправильной. Конечно, маловероятно что такое произойдёт, но ничего исключать нельзя. Хотелось бы реализовать безошибочную систему. Может быть, можно как-то обойти постраничную навигацию, а ориентироваться по ID комментария?

Comment: @vp_arth, Не встречали подобных уже реализованых решений? Не совсем могу понять данный алгоритм.

Comment: По форумам не подскажу, ближайшее, что приходит в голову - переход по ссылке в комментарий на youtube. Комментарий закрепляется вверху ленты вместо скролла к нему непонятно куда внутрь ленты.

Comment: @DeZZer Это с помощью обычной ссортировки можно сделать.. Если перезод по определенной ссылке то сперва искать надо нужный комментарий и первым его выводить